# What was going on with Watts at the very end?

Tags: to-the-moon

> At the end of the game after Watts and Rosalene are talking by Johnny and River's graves in front of the lighthouse, the "world" begins to shake and glow red. It's the same sort of occurrence that Watts and Rosalene experience inside Johnny's "world of memories." Also, immediately experiencing the red shakies, Watts chugs some pain pills he denied being addicted to earlier.

Am I reading into it too much? Or is this alluding to the possibility of Watts and Rosalene's "real world" as being simply another "world of memories"? Were there some other clues dropped pointing towards this? Or is there a better evidenced explanation?

Comment: I'm not the expert at spoiler questions, but I think this one needs some love to clean it up. Anyone?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because of the spoiler?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is... there is no definite answer.

It is like the ending to Inception. Were they in the real world or the dream world at the end? Does it matter?

The answer, if it comes at all, will come in future episodes. The ending of To the Moon implies there will be a sequel with the same two agents and a new patient. This has been confirmed by the designer, Kan Gao.

Answer (score 0):

The screen glows red although the action takes place in the "real" virtual world, in order to convey the fact Dr. Watts is very ill. He is not addicted to painkillers, he swallows them to keep calm the pain. Eva does not know of his condition. The player might miss the jokes he keeps cracking in future episodes.